# How to get the height of table in Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, html-table

How can we get the height of the html table in jQuery. For example if we have the following code then how can we get the height of the table:-

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>

<div>Some Text Here Some Text Here Some Text Here Some Text Here Some Text Here Some Text Here Some Text Here Some Text Here Some Text Here Some Text Here Some Text Here Some Text Here Some Text Here Some Text Here Some Text Here Some Text Here Some Text Here Some Text Here Some Text Here Some Text Here Some Text Here Some Text Here Some Text Here </div>

</td>

<td>

<div>Some Text Here Some Text Here Some Text Here Some Text Here Some Text Here Some Text Here Some Text Here Some Text Here Some Text Here Some Text Here Some Text Here Some Text Here Some Text Here Some Text Here Some Text Here Some Text Here Some Text Here Some Text Here Some Text Here Some Text Here Some Text Here Some Text Here Some Text Here </div>

</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 8):

What about `$('table').height()` or even `$('table').outerHeight()`.

Comment: How to store this in variable if the table has id="abc"

Comment: @JohnPreston Why you not learn jQuery selectors syntax first?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe [this](http://api.jquery.com/height/)?

```
var height = $('#abc').height();
```

Answer (score 1):

With a table like this :

```
<table id="abc">
      ...
</table>
```

The jQuery needed in order to get the height of the above table is :

`var height = $('#abc').height();`